# Recorrer un json , jade

Tags: nodejs, jade

Estoy intentando recorrer un json en jade pero tengo problemas , pues me salen data basura.

```
usuarios={ _id: 57e66c6b0d38b61f3c0e626b, name: 'asdas', lastName: 'dasdasd', userName: 'dasd', password: 'ada', __v: 0 },{ _id: 57e66e16228d2f0674a90af5, name: 'dasdsad', lastName: 'asdasd', userName: 'dsadas', email: 'xxxxxxx', password: 'kevincito11', __v: 0 }}
```

En jade hago lo siguiente para recorrer los usuarios

```
for user in usuarios
   p #{user}
```

Hasta ahi todo bien , me saca todos los usuarios en orden

Ahora quiero recorrer el json para sacar los campos

```
for user in usuarios
  for val,key in user
     p #{key}:#{val}
```

Deberia salir el campo y su valor, pero me sale un monton de cosas innecesarias

```
[object Object]:$__

false:isNew

:errors

[object Object]:_doc

function () { var self = this , hookArgs // arguments eventually passed to the hook - are mutable , lastArg = arguments[arguments.length-1] , pres = this._pres[name] , posts = this._posts[name] , _total = pres.length , _current = -1 , _asyncsLeft = proto[name].numAsyncPres , _asyncsDone = function(err) { if (err) { return handleError(err); } --_asyncsLeft || _done.apply(self, hookArgs); } , handleError = function(err) { if ('function' == typeof lastArg) return lastArg(err); if (errorCb) return errorCb.call(self, err); throw err; } , _next = function () { if (arguments[0] instanceof Error) { return handleError(arguments[0]); } var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) , currPre , preArgs; if (_args.length && !(arguments[0] == null && typeof lastArg === 'function')) hookArgs = _args; if (++_current < _total) { currPre = pres[_current] if (currPre.isAsync && currPre.length < 2) throw new Error("Your pre must have next and done arguments -- e.g., function (next, done, ...)"); if (currPre.length < 1) throw new Error("Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)"); preArgs = (currPre.isAsync ? [once(_next), once(_asyncsDone)] : [once(_next)]).concat(hookArgs); return currPre.apply(self, preArgs); } else if (!_asyncsLeft) { return _done.apply(self, hookArgs); } } , _done = function () { var args_ = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) , ret, total_, current_, next_, done_, postArgs; if (_current === _total) { next_ = function () { if (arguments[0] instanceof Error) { return handleError(arguments[0]); } var args_ = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1) , currPost , postArgs; if (args_.length) hookArgs = args_; if (++current_ < total_) { currPost = posts[current_] if (currPost.length < 1) throw new Error("Your post must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)"); postArgs = [once(next_)].concat(hookArgs); return currPost.apply(self, postArgs); } else if (typeof lastArg === 'function'){ // All post handlers are done, call original callback function return lastArg.apply(self, arguments); } }; // We are assuming that if the last argument provided to the wrapped function is a function, it was expecting // a callback. We trap that callback and wait to call it until all post handlers have finished. if(typeof lastArg === 'function'){ args_[args_.length - 1] = once(next_); } total_ = posts.length; current_ = -1; ret = fn.apply(self, args_); // Execute wrapped function, post handlers come afterward if (total_ && typeof lastArg !== 'function') return next_(); // no callback provided, execute next_() manually return ret; } }; return _next.apply(this, arguments); }:$__original_save
```

¿En que me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con estas dos maneras:

```
div
  each val, index in usuarios
    p= index + ': ' + val



for val,key in usuarios
  p #{key}:#{val}
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay mucha documentación sobre los *maps*:

```
var usuarios = [
    {id:57e6,name:'asdas',lastName:'dasdasd',password:'ada'},
    {id:57e6,name:'apas',lastName:'dasdasd',pasword:'ada'},
    {id:57e6,name:'kejh',lastName:'dasdasd',password:'ada'},
    {id:57e6,name:'oiuyu',lastName:'dasdasd',password:'ada'}
]

for usuario in usuarios
     - var key = Object.keys( usuario )[1]
     - var val = usuario
     p #{key}: #{usuario.name}

// Probado en Codepen, creo que sigue usando Jade
```